# Cocoa Xcode :: How to localize alerts in my app?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, localization, alerts

my app alerts like ( "already exists. Do you want to replace it?") appears in English. My computer is configured in Spanish.

Why?

There is any way to resolve it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> hi, my app alerts like ( "already exists. Do you want to replace it?") appears in English. My computer is configured in Spanish.
>
> Why?

Because your computer knows neither English nor Spanish, and so cannot translate the English strings you entered into Spanish for display.

> There is any way to resolve it?

Provide Spanish strings, and use them. See the [Internationalization Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/).